# 'undefined is not a function' when using unordered bulk upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using a bulk upsert to update/add several documents at once to my database:

```
var bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
docs.forEach(function(doc, index, array){
  bulk.find({'docId' : doc.docId}).upsert().updateOne(doc);
});
bulk.execute();
```

On `bulk.execute` this is returning the following error:

```
/myPath/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:771
  catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                                   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /myPath/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:470:5
```

I have looked at the code in the mongodb module and it seems to be failing on the callback here:

```
// Execute batches
return executeBatches(this, function(err, result) {
  callback(err, result);
});
```

The data is being written to the database exactly as expected, but this error is still being thrown, and I can't work out what I could be doing to cause it.

I have ruled out problems with my data by using trivial objects, and by using bulk inserts instead of upserts as they are simpler, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [invoke bulk.execute with a callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/unordered.html?highlight=bulk#UnorderedBulkOperation).

```
bulk.execute(function(err,results) {
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
    else
        console.log(results);
});
```

Or the like, should work.

Comment: Thanks, literally just figured that out, it's not mentioned in the docs I was looking at.